# Questions on "den niedrigen Flurgang"

Tags: meaning-in-context

An immediate translation of *den niedrigen Flurgang* is *the low hallway* (in a house). That makes me think of a hallway with a *low ceiling*.

However, when taking the context into account, it would make more sense to translate *niedrigen* as *lower*, as in the *lower floor* of the building. But that possibility does not seem to appear in Collins, Cambridge, or other dictionaries I have checked. What would you experts say?

The other question concerns the word *Flurgang*. [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/?q=Flurgang) has one reference, which does not fit this context. Nor does the word appear in the other dictionaries I have checked. Additionally, both *Flur* and *Gang* may mean *corridor*, indicating a duplication. So is anyone here able to shed some light?

Comment: niedringen seems to be misspelled. Could you please check your source and compare it with any dictionary.

Comment: Taking the context into account is kind of difficult if you don't give any context, isn't it?

Comment: You absolutely correctly emphasized twice that the context is important. So why are you hiding this context from us? Why don't you tell us what the context is? It's really hard to answer your question when you withhold important information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Describing the "Flurgang" as "niedrig" will always mean a low ceiling. Would it be in the lower floor it would be "den unteren Flurgang". I do not know any example where "niedrig" is the position of an object.

And yes "Flurgang" as a duplication if it stands in the context of a house. It is a bit uncommon but ok to use.
However "Flurgang" has a second meaning using "Flur" for farmlands or fields and "Gang" as the noun for walking. In this meaning it is a procession through the fields.

And now decide: Is it about a house or an outdoor activity.

Comment: It is the field definition that DWDS provides:  flurgang, m.; solemnis obambulatio finium, feierliche begehung der grenzen einer feldmark, grenzbegang. My question was no doubt about the house. Thank you.